# System generated user id in CloudWatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am checking logs in cloudwatch to see who last deployed to our EB instance and when. To do this, I am filtering the **API Activity History** by resource name.

In the list of actions I see `{Register/Deregister}InstancesWithLoadBalancer` events. Each has the name of the initiating user. Most are the names of users registered in IAM, but every so often there is a user with a system generated id in the form `i-xxxxxxxx`.

"who" is this user and what is happening to cause this event?

Comment: That looks like an instance ID. I'd guess your instances have an IAM role - do your instances have a script to register/deregister themselves during deployments or something?

Comment: Oh. That's it. Someone built it into a deploy pipeline of an unrelated app. Thank you.